# Show sign-up link for non-logged in users instead Buddypress Activity Loop

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

How to show login link for non-logged in users instead Buddypress Activity Loop?

Is there an easy way to do this in theme functions.php file?

I know how to add notice before loop with: *action_activity_loop_start* but how to hide the whole loop?

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

You can use something like this:

```php
add_filter( 'bp_get_template_part', static function( $templates, $slug, $name ) {

    if ( $slug === 'activity/index' && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $templates = [];
    }

    return $templates;
}, 10, 3 );
```

This snippet will completely hide the default activity loop, with all filters, forms, etc, rendering an empty page instead of all BuddyPress Activity.

This may not be a desirable way.

### Option 2

In the `$templates` variable you can also define your own path to a custom template (like `activity/logged-out.php`, so it will look like this:

```php
$templates = [ 'activity/logged-out.php' ];
```

You will need to create a `wp-content/themes/theme-name/buddypress/activity/logged-out.php` file with something like this:

```php
<?php do_action( 'bp_before_directory_activity' ); ?>

<div id="buddypress">

    <?php do_action( 'bp_before_directory_activity_content' ); ?>

    <div id="template-notices" role="alert" aria-atomic="true">
        <?php do_action( 'template_notices' ); ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'bp_before_directory_activity_list' ); ?>

    <div class="activity" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" aria-relevant="all">

        CUSTOM TEXT FOR LOGGED OUT USERS.

    </div><!-- .activity -->

</div>
```

You can check `activity/index.php` file to decide what you need and what you don't, but I think this is a good idea to remove the majority of content and hooks.

### Option 3

If you use the BuddyPress Legacy Template Pack (check in BuddyPress settings) you can copy `/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-templates/bp-legacy/buddypress/activity/index.php` file into your theme: `wp-content/themes/theme-name/buddypress/activity/index.php` and do the modification where needed. Check the line around 235 which has this: `<?php bp_get_template_part( 'activity/activity-loop' ); ?>`.

For BuddyPress Nouveau Template Pack everything is basically the same, but you will need to deal with `wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-templates/bp-nouveau/buddypress/activity/index.php` file. You will need to wrap its `div#activity-stream` into `is_user_logged_in()` check before display the whole div and its content, something like this:

```php
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
    <div id="activity-stream" class="activity" data-bp-list="activity">

            <div id="bp-ajax-loader"><?php bp_nouveau_user_feedback( 'directory-activity-loading' ); ?></div>

    </div><!-- .activity -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

This way you will basically override the default BuddyPress template file with your own.
Please remember about the ajax functionality of the page (filtering etc).